# How to sum objects in array based on condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have two arrays below, arr1 and arr2. I want to calculate the total score of only those people that exist in arr2.

E.g:

```
arr1= [
{completedBy: 1, name: "John", score: 60},
{completedBy: 2, name: "Mike", score: 90},
{completedBy: 3, name: "Bob",  score: 50},
{completedBy: 4, name: "Steve", score: 40},
{completedBy: 5, name: "Rick", score: 10},
{completedBy: 6, name: "Aaron", score: 30},
]

arr2= [
{id: 2, name: "Mike", city: "NY"},
{id: 4, name: "Steve", city: "LA"},
]
```

I expect result score of 130 which is from Mike(90) + Steve(40).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO (there are ***lots*** of questions and answers covering this topic), and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, when you say _people that exist in arr2_ are you differentiating by names only I guess?

Comment: Solved the issue myself but not sure its efficiency as I used nested loops:               
let total=0;
for(let completedBy of arr1){
 for(let id of arr2){
  if(completedBy.completedBy == id.id )
 {
    total+=completedBy.score
  }
 
}
}

console.log(total)

Comment: If you're going to make many such calls, using the same version of `arr1` in each, then there might be some ways to make it more efficient.  But if this is a one-off, and every time you need to do this, the two arrays have different values, then your two-loop solution is fine.

Comment: Also, can `arr1` have duplicated `completedBy` keys?  Could we also have at the end `{completedBy: 1, name: "John", score: 80}`?  There would be different solutions based on whether that answer is yes or no.

Comment: There will be no duplicate of an object in Arr1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and `find`:

```js
const 
 arr1= [
 {completedBy: 1, name: "John", score: 60},
 {completedBy: 2, name: "Mike", score: 90},
 {completedBy: 3, name: "Bob",  score: 50},
 {completedBy: 4, name: "Steve", score: 40},
 {completedBy: 5, name: "Rick", score: 10},
 {completedBy: 6, name: "Aaron", score: 30},
 ],
 arr2= [
 {id: 2, name: "Mike", city: "NY"},
 {id: 4, name: "Steve", city: "LA"},
 ],

result = arr2.reduce((a,o)=>(arr1.find(n=>n.completedBy==o.id)?.score || 0)+a,0);

console.log(result);
```